# Can quartz.net reconfigure jobs when config file changes?

Tags: quartz.net

Im doing a proof of concept with Quartz.Net
A fairly simple scheduling task, the only requirement i have is that a restart of the service it not needed to reconfigure quartz

This is test code

```
        var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
```

Relevant data in app.config

```
  <quartz>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
<!-- Configure Thread Pool -->
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
<!-- Configure Job Store -->
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.JobInitializationPlugin, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="quartz.config" />
```

My job config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quartz xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0"
                overwrite-existing-jobs="true">

  <job>
    <job-detail>
      <name>jobName1</name>
      <group>jobGroup1</group>
      <description>jobDesciption1</description>
      <job-type>Jobs.MyJob, Jobs</job-type>
      <volatile>false</volatile>
      <durable>true</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
    </job-detail>

    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>cronName1</name>
        <group>cronGroup1</group>
        <description>CronTriggerDescription</description>
        <job-name>jobName1</job-name>
        <job-group>jobGroup1</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>

    </trigger>
  </job>
</quartz>
```

The cron expression works and teh job is executed each minute, but if i change the expression to 0 0/5 * * * ? while running the service it still fires each minute. So is there a way to config Quartz.net so that it listens to file changes to the config file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add scan interval definition (seconds) for the plugin:

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.xml.scanInterval" value="10" />
```

After that plugin will periodically check for file changes.

Comment: Sorry, the sample was hidden as it was not surrounded with code tags.

Comment: Cool thanks, I can now see in the debug mode that the config is reparsed, it also says "not overwriting existing jobs". And the trigger time is not changed?

Comment: mmw109's comment: "Where do you put 'overwriteExisting Jobs'. I'm using the example config from sourceforge, but it is not taking changes (e.g. I edit the job name, see the filescan job fire, but the old job name is still going and no new name)."