# Quartz.NET Data Driven Simple Schedule Interval Change?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Using Quartz.NET 2.0 on .NET 4.0, I have a simple scheduler setup like this:

```
var testTrigger = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity( "TestTrigger" )
                .StartAt( startTime ).
                WithSimpleSchedule( x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes( (int)this.TestInterval.Value.TotalMinutes ).RepeatForever() )
                .Build();
```

TestInterval property is populated via app.config. The problem with this is that when a new schedule is needed, I have to restart my entire .exe to get a new value in there. Is there an established pattern for adjusting the interval on the fly?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864971/can-quartz-net-reconfigure-jobs-when-config-file-changes) you might find someusefull hints